# Generate collaboration graphs without CRTP-recursion with dot/Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, dot, crtp

I'm working on Curiously Reccuring Template Patterns (CRTP), and want to generate collaboradion diagrams for the derived classes that I have. When I run doxygen on my project, I get diagrams like these:

[image]

Here I have constrained the maximum depth of the graph. But I still don't like the repetitious left branch. Is it possible to ignore one of these nodes (objective_barrier or objective_barrier<objective_dense...>), or to fuse them together?

Edit:
Non-default doxygen-settings:

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = NO
```

The following simpler example:

```
template <typename Derived>
class A_
{
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo();
    }
};

class B_ : public A_<B_>
{
    void foo()
    {

    }
};
```

Produce this:

[image]

Comment: It is probably not possible to ignore this, but as there is nothing to try it with ... So which version of doxygen? please also provide a small example (including settings different from the default doxygen settings: `doxygen -x`) so we can test something.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to mention that you also have `HAVE_DOT=YES` or is this a system where the executable has been manipulated by the distributor  / packager by setting other defaults than the standard doxygen defaults (The standard doxygen default is `HAVE_DOT=NO`) Note: this is not your fault and setting `HAVE_DOT=YES` was easy. You should maybe also have a look at `HAVE_DOT=NO` and the separate case where `TEMPLATE_RELATIONS=NO`  (might have other, for you, unwanted effects though).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by albert it is possible to disable template relations:

```
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS=NO
```

Which leads to the following graph:

[image]